Looking for some words or phrases
I would like to find some words or short phrases that have the letter sequence E-I-E-I-O. For example:
_ E _ I E ... I _ ... _ ... _ O _ _ _ _
Ans: GENIE IN A BOTTLE
(ignore the ... dots)
I have tried some crossword clue web sites but that has not been helpful since they are of fixed length.

have you tried qat or nutrimatic? seems like they might be up your alley

Thanks. Nutrimatic is closer but I was hoping for something less rigid.  I'll play with them some more and see if I can get it.

What specifically would be "less rigid"?

By less rigid I meant perhaps Pop Culture, people's names, geographical locations, etc.  Not just dictionary words.

One option is the Qat tool at Quinaplus.com. To use it, enter the string '*e*i*e*i*o*' (i.e. your letters of choice separated by asterisks) into the search bar, and it will generate a whole variety of options for you. (The asterisks act as wildcards, representing any number of intermediate letters.)

More detailed instructions about all the ways this tool can be used to find strings that satisfy certain conditions can be found on its help page.

Thanks for the Qat suggestion.  It works but I'm looking for something more along the lines of what @juicifer posted in his comment suggesting Nutrimatic.  I'm getting closer but I'm not quite there yet.

@BobBaerker Note also that in juicifer's Qat link, the dictionary was set to 'Union' (rather than default 'UKACD' in mine), which gives you even more options. If you want phrases, focus on the longer results; if it only returns the first 1000 results (and thus mainly the shorter ones, due to ordering by result length) you can specify (e.g.) only phrases having 20+ letters by typing '20-:' before the string of letters and asterisks. And if you want a particular number of characters between two particular letters, replace the asterisk with the desired number of '.' characters as a placeholder.

Thank you for the suggestions.  Per your example, I have tried the following coding.  Ignore the parentheses. The first one yields answers that begin with 20xx.  The last two won't parse.  Please provide the exact coding that works. Thank you.

For a "less rigid" solution, you could try the Crossword Solver  at wordsmithingtools.com, which I created to get around some limitations I ran into with qat, nutrimatic, etc. when trying to create and solve puzzles.
The pattern *e*i*e*i*o* will find words with these letters in them.
It has multiple dictionaries...
The extensive dictionary includes all sorts of results, such as people like "CELINEDION", phrases like "CHANGEDIRECTION", and even puns like "CELINEDIJON".  There are also some interesting dictionaries limited to things like Geographics places, Celestial objects, Animals, and Elements.

Yes, Wordsmithing came up with some 'less rigid' answers.  Thanks for that suggestion.
